# Can a Dialogflow agent repeat the user’s response?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, artificial-intelligence, dialogflow-es

I’m trying to build a Dialogflow agent to repeat a user’s response but haven’t found a solution yet

Is this possible with Dialogflow or any other cloud AI platforms?

The ideal scenario would kinda be like this:

User: “Straws, turtles and everything in between”

Bot: “Okay, so let’s have Straws, turtles and everything in between”

Answer (score 0):

An agent could be trained to reply with your specific needs. For example you can input multiple [training phrases](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/es/docs/intents-training-phrases) depending on what your bot will be doing.

[image]

When the agent is trained with your needs, you can specify what the agent will do with the user input. You can set different [action and parameters](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/es/docs/intents-actions-parameters) depending on the user input. The [Dialogflow documentation](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/es/docs/intents-actions-parameters#required) has an example on how this works. Here is a sample interaction on how it will look like:

> User: I'd like to buy a t-shirt.
>
> Agent: How many do you want? User: 3
>
> Agent: What color would you like?
>
> User: Black
>
> Agent: What size?
>
> User: Medium
>
> Agent: Got it, that was three black t-shirts in medium

You can try following this [Dialogflow quick start](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/es/docs/quick/build-agent) as this implements your use case.